# Is it SAFE to add a 18.04 repo in 20.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I know that it is possible to add 18.04 repos in 20.04 (by manually adding a keyserver and adding a .list file in sources.list.d) but (if all the dependencies are corrected) is it safe to add them? Will it break your computer/Ubuntu installation? Thanks!

Running Ubuntu 20.04. Dual Boot with Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, it should be perfectly safe, as you can always remove them again. I'm personally using Docker and Webmin repos with no problems whatsoever.

Comment: In theory, adding an older repository will usually accomplish nothing, because apt will select newer software from the newer repository. In your specific case, you are asking for surety of a configuration that is **untested**, so we don't know.  Perhaps it will break your system, perhaps it won't. For more specific advice, provide specifics.

Comment: Both Yes and No, different use cases, different hardware configs can break your system. Different library/package versions may disrupt usage too. Not advisable really.

Comment: A *bionic* repo will have it's *depends* and like rules setup for of course *bionic*, so all evaluation of being safe or not falls on you. Adding the repository should be *safe* as it's an older one, however you'll need to evaluate every package yourself as to any consequences as it'll depend what you bring in, and whether or not you get into *dep-hell* (which may not be evident until *release-upgrade* time comes)..  The effects maybe *mine-fields* you'll discover sometime in the future.

Comment: Technically it can be added but I would not recommend it. In case you are installing some application and its dependencies going to break existing other application in systems. it can break dependency tree and will end up in mess. Here scenario depends on application to application and its dependencies. 

 Best thing would be install version's own source list and install any other application via deb packages or compiling source code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it can be added but I would not recommend it. In case you are installing some application and its dependencies going to break existing other application in systems. it can break dependency tree and will end up in mess. Here scenario depends on application to application and its dependencies.

I would suggest installing any other applications (which are not available through Ubuntu version's official repos or any other third party repo),  via deb packages or compiling source code.